# List of unique fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table containing the following data

```
Modifieddate, Frequency  

2015-01-15   Ad-hoc  
2015-01-19   Weekly  
2015-01-20   Weekly  
2016-09-23   Ad-hoc  
2016-09-25   Ad-hoc  
2017-09-20   Monthly
```

I would like to group this table to show when the table went from Ad-Hoc to Weekly and from Weekly to Ad-hoc again. I don't want to know when the table went from weekly to weekly. The end table should look like this.

```
Startdate, Enddate, Frequency 

2015-01-15 2015-01-19 Ad-hoc  
2015-01-19 2016-09-23 Weekly  
2016-09-23 2017-09-20 Ad-hoc  
2017-09-20 getdate()  Monthly
```

How will you do that?

Comment: Do you not intend to run this query for about 6 months? Do you really want a result with a StartDate later than its EndDate, for that last row?

Comment: Ahh - I didn't see that. That date is a typo. I don't have any dates after today so it would say 2017-02-20 instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double `GROUP BY` operation can find this data:

```
declare @t table (ModifiedDate date,Frequency varchar(19))
insert into @t(ModifiedDate, Frequency) values
('20150115','Ad-hoc'),
('20150119','Weekly'),
('20150120','Weekly'),
('20160923','Ad-hoc'),
('20160925','Ad-hoc'),
('20170220','Monthly')

;With Ends as (
    select t1.ModifiedDate as StartAt,MIN(t2.ModifiedDate) as EndAt,t1.Frequency
    from
        @t t1
            inner join
        (select * from @t union all select GETDATE(),'dfdhfhdsfjfh') t2
            on
                t1.Frequency != t2.Frequency and
                t1.ModifiedDate < t2.ModifiedDate
    group by
        t1.ModifiedDate,t1.Frequency
)
select MIN(StartAt) as StartAt,EndAt,Frequency from Ends
group by EndAt,Frequency
order by StartAt
```

Results:

```
StartAt    EndAt                   Frequency
---------- ----------------------- -------------------
2015-01-15 2015-01-19 00:00:00.000 Ad-hoc
2015-01-19 2016-09-23 00:00:00.000 Weekly
2016-09-23 2017-02-20 00:00:00.000 Ad-hoc
2017-02-20 2017-03-13 11:54:39.277 Monthly
```

(Noting that I've tweaked the last row based on comments).

This works by finding, for *every* row, the earliest row that has a different `Frequency` value. This means that, say, a group of `Ad-hoc` rows which are adjacent will locate the *same* succeeding row with a `Weekly` value. That's what the CTE/first `GROUP BY` is doing.

So, if we then take all of those rows and find the earliest of them, we've successfully hidden the existence of the intervening rows - that's what the second `GROUP BY` is doing.

Comment: This is just fantastic - thank you so much Damien_The_Unbeliever for this beaut.

Comment: I have just one more request - what do you do if you have a ID number in the table. Like, if the first three rows have an ID of 30 and the Last three rows have ID = 40?